# Stuck in a user log-in loop on startup (fresh install)

Tags: login, password, login-screen

So I wanted to set up my [Lenovo Flex 2-15D](http://www.staples.ca/fr/Lenovo-Portatif-Flex-2-15D-59424917-15-6-po-RAM-8-Go/product_1148177_2-CA_2_20001) to dual-boot Ubuntu alongside the pre-installed Windows 8.1. I installed the Universal USB Installer from pendrivelinux.com, created a USB stick loaded with Ubuntu 14.10, rebooted (leaving the UEFI settings to their defaults), and got to the installation guide without any problems.

Once I completed the installation, I rebooted once more and made it to the log-in screen. This is where, despite having a fair level of confidence in the password I just created, I kept receiving the "incorrect password" error message. I was annoyed, but it's not the first time I've screwed this kind of thing up, so I followed the instructions here: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

and here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

It worked fairly well. But now when I try to log in with my new password, the screen goes black, and then simply loads the log-in screen again! It seems there are others on this site with the same problem as well, but I couldn't find any with a proper solution.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get rid of your issue. Once you are booted up to the blank desktop... press **CTRL + ALT + F1.**

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install unity
apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*
apt-get install nvidia-prime

shutdown -r now
```

Hope this helps!